# What is the most efficient way to reload CSS after adding data dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This row was added after an ajax call:

```
<tr id="product1" class = "success">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>product one</td>
</tr>
```

the class `success` puts a green background to the row, but obviously this style is lost because the row was added dynamically.

I've seen solutions by dynamic loads of CSS, but I want to know which would be the most efficient if you get to have an extensive stylesheet.
thanks

i'm using boostrap:

```
        <table id = "table_result" class="table">
          <thead id ="table_result_search">
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Product</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Stock</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

and Jquery:

```
//ajax
var tr = TrTableResult(id,nombre, stock, price, n);
$("#table_result_search").append(tr);
//fin ajax
function TrTableResult(id,nombre,stock,price,n){
var color = new Array("success", "error", "warning", "info");
var tr = '<tr id ="'+id+'" class="' + color[n] + '">';  
  tr+= '<td>'+ id +'</td>';
  tr+= '<td>'+ product+'</td>';
  tr+= '<td>'+ price +'</td>'; 
  tr+= '<td>'+ stock +'</td>'; 
  tr+= '</tr>';
  return tr;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to reload CSS : it's always applied, even to dynamically added elements.

Comment: *"...but obviously this style is lost because the row was added dynamically."* That's not obvious at all. CSS is applied to elements that match the selectors, whether they're added dynamically or not.

Comment: How do you load your content with ajax? Please post your JS script

Comment: Why do you think it's lost? I think this should work as expected, if it doesn't, the problem might be somewhere else. Post the CSS class, please.

Comment: you dont have to reload the css have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/eQeZg/3/

Comment: @ahren - Who told you that you can't have spaces in between?

Comment: var color = new Array("success", "error", "warning", "info");
    var tr = '<tr id ="'+id+'" class="' + color[n] + '">';

I'm using bootstrap and when I add a row dynamically, the css does not work, I guess it's because the DOM is already loaded

Comment: hmm, I stand corrected and deleted that comment. However, it seems pointless and confusing to have spaces inbetween attributes and their values.

Comment: @JohnPaulCárdenas - CSS is dynamic, which means it will automatically apply to every newly-added elements.

Comment: @JohnPaulCárdenas: *"...I guess it's because the DOM is already loaded..."* No, that's not it, as several of us have now pointed out. :-) There's something **else** going on.

Comment: @ahren: *"...However, it seems pointless and confusing to have spaces inbetween attributes and their values..."* I strongly recommend not making *style* value judgements. People are quite fierce about their coding/markup styles. :-)

Comment: @JohnPaulCárdenas: I've updated my answer. The problem is that your new row doesn't match the relevant selector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

Now that you've quoted your markup and code, it's clear that you do have the `table` class, so the original answer below isn't it.

But note that you're appending your `tr` to your `thead` element:

```
$("#table_result_search").append(tr);
```

Where your markup is:

```
<thead id ="table_result_search">
```

You're not seeing any effect of the `success` class because the rule is:

```
.table tbody tr.success > td {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

Note the `tbody` in there. So the selector doesn't match, because you're appending the row to a `thead`, not a `tbody`.

---

**Original answer**:

As several of us have pointed out in the comments, CSS is applied by the browser to all elements that match the relevant selectors, whether added dynamically or not.

If the problem is that the `success` class doesn't seem to be working, it's probably that you're missing the `table` class from your `table` element (yes, really).

The rule in bootstrap's CSS is:

```css
.table tbody tr.success > td {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

Note that it starts with a class selector (`.table`), not a tag selector (`table`).

So for instance, this markup will **not** apply those styles to the `td` in this table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="product1" class = "success">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>product one</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ihabak/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ihabak/1/edit)

But this markup (only change is to the `table` tag) will:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="product1" class = "success">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>product one</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ihabak/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ihabak/2/edit)

Comment: Department of redundancy department ;-)

Comment: thanks, I made a mistake I had to charge the "tbody" and was loading the "thead", thank you very much everyone for your responses.